# Laravel 4 Form: Image file upload with text fields

Tags: php, laravel-4

I would like to design a form in Laravel which takes an image the User has selected, uploads it to the server and stores the image path in a `'image'` field and also accepts a `'text'` field which describes the image.  I do not know how to store both the text field and image as an array to pass to the controller.

**The Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('description', trans('main.poster')) }}
{{ Form::text('description', Input::old('poster'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::file('image','files' => true) }}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{ trans('dash.update') }}</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store()
{

$input = array('image' => Input::file('image'));

    if ( ! $this->validator->setRules('image')->with($input)->passes())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($this->validator->errors());
    }

    $this->title->uploadImage($input);

    return Redirect::back()->withSuccess( trans('main.uploaded image success')        );
```

**Upload image**

```
public function uploadImage(array $input)
{   
 $name  = str_random(25);
    $insert = array('image' => asset('assets/images/'.$name.'.jpg'), );

    $this->images->saveTitleImage($input, $name);


}
```

**Save image path**

```
public function saveTitleImage($input, $name)
{
    $encoded = Imagine::make($input['image']->getRealPath())
        ->encode('jpg');

    Imagine::make($encoded)->save(public_path('assets/images/'.$name.'.jpg'));  
}
```

Comment: Well for starters, the `files => true` should be on the Form::open() call not on your Form::file(), see: http://laravel.com/docs/html#opening-a-form